# svn: Querying mergeinfo requires version 3 of the FSFS filesystem schema;

Tags: svn, fsfs

I get this error when trying to query mergeinfo.

```
$ svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible  https://svn.hq.corp/trunk  https://svn.hq.corp/branches/RC-1

svn: Querying mergeinfo requires version 3 of the FSFS filesystem schema; filesystem '/mnt/svn/co/db' uses only version 1
```

I could not find any information on how to upgrade FSFS from version 1 to version 3

What i wanted to accomplish, was to trace revisions across branches

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can upgrade your repository to the latest schema version with this:

```
    svnadmin upgrade /mnt/svn/co
```

After you also have upgraded the Subversion package.

Answer (score 14):

I had faced the same error `svn: Querying mergeinfo requires version 3 of the FSFS filesystem schema` on svn "Show History" request in IDE after upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 13.

See http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/subversion-1-8-and-intellij-idea-13/ on svn handling changes.

The error remained with both Subverion 1.6 and 1.8 client and working copy format.

Initial guess was that painful repository format upgrade on server is unavoidable.

But then I tried deselecting IDEA's `Settings\Version Control\Subversion\Presentation\Show merge source in history and annotations` option.

After that both 1.6 and 1.8 working copy format is usable in IDEA with ancient FSFS filesystem version 1 repository on server. 
It's just needed to ensure that client version matches wc format.

`mergeinfo` proved not to be indispensable after all.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this issue. i got following error. 
Error:
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 501 'Method Not Implemented' on '/XXX/!svn/XXX/13198/trunk/XXX'
svn: E200007: Additional errors:
svn: E200007: Querying mergeinfo requires version 3 of the FSFS filesystem schema; filesystem '/var/www/svn/XXX/db' uses only version 2
Solution:
1. Check that your svn repository server version and svn client version are same or different.
2. Example if your svn repository server version is 1.6 and your svn client (silksvn) version is 1.8 or greater than or less than your svn repository server version.
3. you should install the svn client version same as your svn sever repository version.

if svn server version is 1.6 than you have to install svn client of 1.6 version.
I have solved this issue. definitely it will work.
Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to merge with TortoiseSVN.
I could not update the repository server as it is shared with others projects.

I did the merge using Eclipse with SVNKit 1.8.1 connector, and CollabNet Desktop merge implémentation.

Works like a charm :)

Comment: Another option while merging with TortoiseSVN is to deselect "all revisions" in the Merge revision range options and to select "specific range". Then select all revision (beware only the first 100 are displayed, you have to click "Show all" before). This will prevent Tortoise to launch the mergeinfo command and the merge will work.

Comment: Ben's comment here should be the answer.  Just choose the head revision and you'll avoid this issue